# Gumby 2 Toggle does not work

Tags: html, mobile, frameworks, toggle, gumby-framework

I downloaded Gumby 2 and incorporated it into my website. Unfortunately when you access it on a mobile device the toggle which SHOULD open the navigation fails to appear. I am not sure why it does this and I know I have placed all of the correct code into my html website. Hopefully someone here can help me.

Website is here - http://vortexradio.co.uk feel free to view the source to try and help.

Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `gumby-trigger="#nav1 > something .something"` but your navigation element is `id="#nav3"`

Comment: Changed the trigger to #nav3 but that doesn't fix it.